# Devexpress gridview select and unselect groupwise

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a devexpress grid view in my asp.net web application.Now I can group and select all rows grid wise from header part. I need to select the rows under a group separately without selecting the whole grid rows. Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**How to implement select/unselect for all rows in a group row**
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1760

On right side you can run example in browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this:** [ASPxGridView - How to implement select/unselect for all rows in a group row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1760)

A similar issue was discussed in the ASPxGridView - [How to select multiple rows with a mouse click without pressing the 'Ctrl' key](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q385530.aspx) thread. I hope that you find this information helpful.

More references:
[ASPxGridView - How to implement select/unselect for all rows in a group row using multiple grouping](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q518322)
[How to select data rows and group rows in multiple grouping.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q256480)
[ASPxGridView - AllowSelectByRowClick MultiSelect without holding Ctrl key.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T140294)
[ASPxGridView - Unable to select multiple rows by row click when AllowSelectByRowClick="True"](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q331855)